# Firefox process dies after SSH logout on remote machine

Tags: linux, ssh

I need to run a Firefox process on a remote host via SSH and also keep the process running even after logging out. I already have tried these ways:

- nohup firefox &
- screen
- disown -h

... but it seems these work only for processes without hardware display, because these work fine with my scripts and I can keep my scripts running even after an SSH logout, but I can't do the same for Firefox.

Comment: I assume that you are logging into a remote machine using `ssh` then run `firefox &`. Does firefox appear on your screen And is my aasumption correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using x-forwarding I don't expect this can be easily done. You should consider using VNC or a similar solution like NX (freeNX).

VNC is like a "remote desktop" but it's cross-platform. If this is Linux you're using, you must likely have a package for it (for example, Debian/Ubuntu has a vnc-server package). It's fairly popular and if you Google for vnc and the name of your distro, you will likely find instructions written specifically for your distro.

FreeNX is more interesting if you have to access the machine over a low-bandwidth connection. If you're doing this all on your LAN, I wouldn't worry about it. It might be more difficult finding
specific instructions on setting this one up.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how to do what you are suggesting(am kind of newbie for linux) !

Comment: Although I like VNC, and have used it for years, it can be a bit of a bear to set up, especially if there are NATing firewalls involved. Some versions have issues with Win7 desktops. Consider the free versions [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/)  or [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the follow:

```
nohup firefox --detach & disown
```

or

```
nohup firefox-esr --detach & disown
```